# Java number pattern two triangle side by side to make a square/rectangle

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, numbers

I want the output to look like this:

[image]

How can I arrange these loops to get two triangle number pattern? And how can I improve my code. New in JAVA :-)

```
    for (int i = 1; i<=10; i++ ) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for (int count = 1; count <= 10; count++) {
        for (int index=1; index < count+1; index++)
            System.out.print(" ");

        for (int num=10; num >count; num--) {
            System.out.print(num);
        }   
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
for (int row = 1; row <= 10; row++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= row; j++) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("  ");
    for (int j = 10; j >= row; j--) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
1   10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
1 2   10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 
1 2 3   10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 
1 2 3 4   10 9 8 7 6 5 4 
1 2 3 4 5   10 9 8 7 6 5 
1 2 3 4 5 6   10 9 8 7 6 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7   10 9 8 7 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8   10 9 8 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9   10 9 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10   10
```

Explanation - the outer loop iterates over the rows, so I've renamed `i` to `row` for clarity. The first inner loop is unchanged from your code - it is responsible for printing the numbers before the diagonal. We then print a double space (`System.out.print("  ")`) and the second loop then prints the rest of the numbers, starting from 10 and down to the row number.

On a different note, you should format your code better. Indentation really helps with readability and comprehension.

For instance, your first loop looks like this:

```
  for(int i = 1; i<=10; i++ ) {
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print(j);
    }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

But should look like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

It's the same code, but in the formatted version it's much easier to see that the second `System.out.println` statement follows the inner `for` and that the final closing bracket closes the outer `for` loop and not something else.